# How to fix UV Map Issue?

Tags: modeling, uv

I want to fix the part I have marked in the image below.

I tried to apply scale, rotation, location and nothing happens. What can I do to solve this? And what PBR shader do you recommend for blender 2.78a?

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if it is about the flared out UVs, you might try to unwrap with 'Project from View', from a front or back orthographic viewport. Also, the Principled BDSF shader is *the* pbr shader for Blender.

Comment: @Adam i its not included in this version and i cannot update my blender to 2.79 or 2.78b-c , thats why i am asking which its the best pbr shader for blender 2.78a. if i pack the islands it will be well scaled after doing the project from view unwrapping??

Comment: Oops, my mistake. For pre-principled shader, it is a little more complicated. Physically based rendering is a philosophy that uses a variety of shaders to achieve  realism. Tutorials I have watched use mostly diffuse, reflection, refraction, Fresnel and a few others. As for the mapping, I think you can just select those faces (isolated by a seam) and remap those with project from view. I'll work on some stuff to see if I'm even right about that, then give you a more concise answer if I can.

Comment: well there are a few like remingtons pbr shader , blender gurus pbr shader too, and other ones that can be found in youtube but i am not sure which its better to use.

Comment: @Adam seems that i fix it tho...i change it to conformal instead, but its annoying to uv map part by part >_< [link] (https://files.gamebanana.com/bitpit/screenshot_-_01172019_-_10_35_03_pm.png) [link] (https://files.gamebanana.com/bitpit/screenshot_-_01172019_-_10_35_17_pm.png)     danmed i dont know how to insert links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix it

I had to unwrap my mesh with conformal option and that's it.

[image]
[image]